# AppFabric Cache - Is it reasonable to allocate two cache clusters?

Tags: asp.net, .net, memcached, appfabric

My first impression of AppFabric Cache is that it's essentially a distributed hashtable in the same vein as [memcached](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached). The typical usage pattern of such a cache is that there is no guarantee that your data will be in the cache (old entries are evicted to make space for new ones), but with sufficient RAM they usually will be.

On the other hand MS provide a [Web Session State Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361709%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) that stores session data in an AppFabric Cache. This appears to be a completely different usage pattern as we now require the cached items to never be evicted as a result of memory pressure. To achieve this MS provide a high-availability mode that keeps redundant copies of all data, furthermore eviction can be disabled, which in turn requires us to allocate sufficient RAM to ensure that the cache never reaches capacity.

It seems likely that an application would benefit from using both types/modes of cache, but as far as I can tell AppFabric RAM cannot be ringfenced *within* a cluster or host, hence the web session state may (and generally will) experience memory pressure in that case. The only solution I can see is to operate two AppFabric Cache clusters, one for each mode.

Is the above a good representation of the situation or am I missing some config setting that addresses this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Storing a session in appfabric is not a good idea,have faced many problems trying this(like due to memory pressure data got lost, multiple users hitting the cache to put the data can lead to data loss etc.) and now started using inProc/SqlServer session state use.

Comment: For web session state you should either enable high reliability, disable expiry and provision ample RAM. Alternatively you can persist state to a backing store such as SQL Server. To achieve the main benefit from the backing store approach the write-through pattern needs to be used so that the writes are asynchronous and decoupled from the cache writes (so the caller doesn't have to wait for each write to complete - which would be no net gain from just using SQL svr directly for cache writes - reads would be faster of course, or use sticky sessions and cached sessions in RAM at the web server)

Comment: well to use HA there are some environment related bottlenecks at my side. I feel sticky session is good and reliable option.